# How to provide the same 3rd party dependencies to multiple gradle projects without copying/pasting large amounts of code?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

If I have 10-15 3rd party dependencies that need to be included in X amount of Gradle projects, what is the best and most efficient way of doing that?

Option 1)

Copy/paste each dependency in each project's build.gradle.  Lots of duplication of code.

Option 2)

Create a new project that includes all of these 3rd party dependencies, and replace the 3rd party dependency declarations in each of the projects' build.gradle with a dependency declaration for the new project.  Still duplication of code, but much less than Option 1.

Option 3)

Something smarter, if it exists???

Comment: The best way depends on circumstances and might be a matter of opinion (and thus off topic). Generally the concept of shared versions is called bill-of-materials BOM, and is supported in several ways. If you search for that, you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547170/in-gradle-how-do-i-declare-common-dependencies-in-a-single-place, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896971/maven-bom-dependencies-in-gradle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687995/publish-bom-as-pom-xml-using-gradle-plugin-java-platform

Comment: Also I assume you mean independent gradle projects, not submodules in a game Multimodule project. If that is what you meant, you should make it explicit in the question, but then your question would likely be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option (2) is what you're looking for.

This is essentially what Spring Boot starters are. For example, the `spring-boot-starter-json` [provides (6) dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-json/build.gradle#L9..L14).

With that said, option (2) can either be:

1. A submodule/subproject of another project
2. Dedicated project

For either choice, the library project will need to either be published or included within the final artfiact (fat/uber JAR)